# i want to load dynamic pages by using javascript...

Tags: ajax

i want to load dynamic pages by using javascript-ajax...
i have side(vertical) tabs just like facebook has(which is on left side) and right side which shows the content(page) of that tab. when i will click on any tab the content(page) should be loaded on right side......i didnt mean loading a whole page. i mean changing divs of that right side....one more example of youtube home....in youtube on left side we have channels to which we subscribe, when we click on any of that tab, videos are loaded of that channel..
how to do this....any link to example? please share

Comment: i am unable to start or get anything...if you have know if there is any example on any blog or site then pls tell me....thanks for your concern

Comment: this is what i found.
this is the original demo.
http://www.kfsoft.info/MyGoogleStyleFloatingMenu/demo.php
and this is my implementation.
http://www.testmycode.co.nr/
pls tell me whats the problem